# Simple Boost.Locale example doesn't work

Tags: c++, boost, locale

I copy/pasted the [conversions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions_8cpp-example.html) example verbatim into an [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/89a619014b10beaa) that allows Boost:

```
//
//  Copyright (c) 2009-2011 Artyom Beilis (Tonkikh)
//
//  Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
//  accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
//  http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/case_conv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
int main()
{
    using namespace boost::locale;
    using namespace std;
    // Create system default locale
    generator gen;
    locale loc=gen(""); 
    locale::global(loc); 
    cout.imbue(loc);

    cout<<"Correct case conversion can't be done by simple, character by character conversion"<<endl;
    cout<<"because case conversion is context sensitive and not 1-to-1 conversion"<<endl;
    cout<<"For example:"<<endl;
    cout<<"   German grüßen correctly converted to "<<to_upper("grüßen")<<", instead of incorrect "
                    <<boost::to_upper_copy(std::string("grüßen"))<<endl;
    cout<<"     where ß is replaced with SS"<<endl;
    cout<<"   Greek ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ is correctly converted to "<<to_lower("ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ")<<", instead of incorrect "
                    <<boost::to_lower_copy(std::string("ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ"))<<endl;
    cout<<"     where Σ is converted to σ or to ς, according to position in the word"<<endl;
    cout<<"Such type of conversion just can't be done using std::toupper that work on character base, also std::toupper is "<<endl;
    cout<<"not even applicable when working with variable character length like in UTF-8 or UTF-16 limiting the correct "<<endl;
    cout<<"behavior to unicode subset BMP or ASCII only"<<endl;

}
// vim: tabstop=4 expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4
// boostinspect:noascii
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_locale` and this doesn't perform the correct conversions. `grüßen` doesn't become `GRÜSSEN` and `ὈΔΥΣΣΕΎΣ` doesn't become `ὀδυσσεύς`.

Comment: Well, I guess, the /problem/ is in environment. Works perfectly for me on several Linuxes (of various distros). Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331487/string-conversion-with-boost-locale-different-behaviour-on-windows-and-linux

Comment: Now we know that "grüßen" *doesn't* become. Are you going to tell us what it *does* become on your system?

Comment: The outcome depends on your locale. For instance on my machine the result is incorrect if I run with `export LANG=de_DE && ./main` and correct if I run with `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8 && ./main`. This is no surprise as without utf-8 the more interesting characters don't exist.